# reopen closed tabs in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

Is there any way to reopen closed tabs on DataGrip? not recently closed :)

Answer (score 12):

Ctrl+E or Cmd+E opens up a window with a list of recent files. Click on any to open it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are about consoles: go to Files tool window, expand Scratches and Consoles -> Database Consoles -> Data source name -> you'll find here all consoles ever created and modified.